# Init jce editor with a specific profile

Tags: joomla

I'm trying to find a way to initialize the Joomla 2.5.2 jce editor via javascript with a specific profile.
Right now I've got the following code which is called via an ajax-request:

```
$wysiwyg =& JFactory::getEditor();
echo $wysiwyg->display(
    "editor", 
    JRequest::getString("value"), 
    JRequest::getInt("width"), 
    JRequest::getInt("height"), 
    40, 
    6, 
    array(
    )
);
$document =& JFactory::getDocument();
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
echo $document->_script["text/javascript"];
echo "</script>";
```

This initializes the jce editor with the default profile, but I want to init a custom profile I added. Is this something I can configure?

By the way, is there a better way to initialize the editor via javascript?